# locate resource through R class member in eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse

How do I locate resource (in .xml file) through R class member like `R.id.some_text_view`?
It would be handy in eclipse if `F3` can find the resource but it finds the definition in R.java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the latest ADT, it's very simple to do.

First make sure you have your project compiled.

Lets say you have a code like

```
myCheckBox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.my_check_box);
```

Just press the CTRL key and while holding it down, hover your mouse cursor over the my_check_box, and it'll show you a pop up that says "Open declaration in..." and show you the XML file, which you can click to go straight to it =)